# Trouble getting write-progress in for each loop

Tags: powershell

So i am filling a CheckedList in a powershell form with:

```
    $BTN_GetGroups_Click = {
    $CLB_Groups.Items.Clear()
    $MemberofGroups = foreach ($Group in (Get-MsolGroup -tenantid $CMB_id.Text -all)) { if (Get-MsolGroupMember -tenantid $CMB_id.Text -all -GroupObjectId $Group.ObjectId | where { $_.Emailaddress -eq $CMB_Users.text }) { $Group.Displayname } }
    
    foreach ($MemberofGroup in $MemberofGroups)
    {
        $CLB_Groups.Items.Add($memberofGroup)
    }
}
```

This is working fine. My goal is to retreive all groups of all sorts a user is member of.

Problem is, this process can be very time consuming depending on the amount of groups. So
while this process runs, the form kind of freezes, en leaves the person who runs this script in doubt and wondering what the progress is...

So i came op with the idea to build a progress bar in the gui. that failed...
Then i thought i could use these line to let a progress bar pop-up:

```
$i =1
        foreach ($group in $Memberofgroups)
            {
            $Progress = [math]::Round(($i/$Memberofgroups.count)*100)
            write-progress -activity "Scanning DFS Connections" -status "$Progress% Complete:" -percentcomplete $Progress
            $i++
            }
```

Problem is i cannot wrap my head around how to incorporate these lines in my code.
Goal is to get the actual progress of this line:

```
$MemberofGroups = foreach ($Group in (Get-MsolGroup -tenantid $CMB_id.Text -all)) { if (Get-MsolGroupMember -tenantid $CMB_id.Text -all -GroupObjectId $Group.ObjectId | where { $_.Emailaddress -eq $CMB_Users.text }) { $Group.Displayname } }
```

Because that line is the time consuming part i want the progress on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the result of the `Get-MsolGroup` call in a variable, so you know the total number of groups beforehand. Then the task becomes easy:

```
$Groups = Get-MsolGroup -tenantid $CMB_id.Text -all
$i = 1

$MemberofGroups = foreach ($Group in $Groups) { 

    if (Get-MsolGroupMember -tenantid $CMB_id.Text -all -GroupObjectId $Group.ObjectId | where { $_.Emailaddress -eq $CMB_Users.text }) { 
        $Group.Displayname 
    }

    $Progress = [math]::Round(($i/$Groups.count)*100)
    write-progress -activity "Getting group members" -status "$Progress% Complete:" -percentcomplete $Progress    
    $i++ 
}

# Remove progress bar when finished
write-progress -activity "Getting group members" -completed
```

Comment: Zett42, that worked like a charm! thank you! Only issue is that the progress bar is not closing when 100%

Comment: @BarryBadpak I've added code to remove progress bar.